# Remove all CSS properties from an element and its children

Tags: javascript, css

The title says it all. Is it possible to make an element and all its children lose all CSS properties?

Demo:

```
<div class="class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div">
<!-- content + children -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div {
    background-color: green;
}

.class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div > .content {
   /* tons of other properties */
}
```

This example is just to make you understand, the actual situation is different. The element, that I want to STAY AWAY from CSS properties consists of tons of child elements. I can't gather all the classes and ids and undo the effects. I need some dynamic solution, probably via JS.

EDIT: Without removing the class and id attributes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

Comment: @SuperDJ dude! This is exactly what I was looking for. I got the solution, I have to add `all:unset` to the parent and all its children. Never used or heard about this property before. You can post it as the answer.

Comment: @saibbyweb you also want to remove the properties of nested children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) property to `unset` all properties.

```css
body { font-size: small; background-color: #F0F0F0; color:blue; }
blockquote { background-color: skyblue;  color: red; }
blockquote { all: unset; }
```

```html
<blockquote id="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</blockquote> Phasellus eget velit sagittis.
```

> Snippet from linked source

Answer (score 1):

You can establish `all: initial;` inside parent `div` for restoring defaul CSS inside it. Once done that, you can establish new CSS styles on its childrens.

Here is a definition of CSS `all` clause:

> The all property resets all properties, apart from unicode-bidi and direction, to their initial or inherited value (all: initial | inherit | unset;).

- **initial:** Changes all the properties applied to the element or the element's parent to their initial value
- **inherit:** Changes all the properties applied to the element or the element's parent to their parent value
- **unset:** Changes all the properties applied to the element or the element's parent to their parent value if they are inheritable or to their initial value if not

```css
body { 
    /* Set CSS for all document */
    color: green; 
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div {
    /* Set CSS for all DIVs */
    background-color: blue;
    border: solid 7px black;
}

.class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div {
    all: initial; /* Set default CSS */
}

.class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div > .content {
    /* Set new CSS for DIV childrens with "content" class */
    background-color: yellow;
    color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="class-defined-but-should-affect-the-div">
    I have got CSS styles
</div>

<div class="class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div">
    I have not got CSS styles
    <br/>
    <label class="content"> I have got new CSS styles</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just simply remove CSS properties of an element. You can overwrite them or remove its `class` or `id`.

The best approach is to have a toggle class.

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
  document.getElementsByClassName('class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div')[0].classList.remove('toggle');
}, 2500);
```

```css
.class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: grey;
}
.toggle.class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
}
.toggle.class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div * { /* all children */
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 5px;
}
.toggle.class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle class-defined-but-should-not-affect-the-div">
  <div>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP: "EDIT: Without removing the class and id attributes."

Comment: Not removing the actuall class. I am talking about an toggle class. It has the same effect.